# Parsing issue in IOS

Tags: objective-c, json

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@&user_type=%@",_emailID.text,_password.text,@"normal"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
}] resume];
```

i have this code I'm getting response but i don't know how to parse the response.

This is response
requestReply: {"user_id":"400","email":"omer.osman@gmail.com","name":"Omer","number":"1234567","password":"pass","user_type":null}

Comment: Is `NSASCIIStringEncoding` really intended? Usually the data is UTF8 encoded. And what answer do you expect without giving any information what the response contains?

Comment: i have  use this code from stack overflow and just change the url and parameters according to mine and its displaying correct response. but i want to parse the response. @vadian

Comment: can u explain related to my code? @MahipalSingh

Comment: JSON is only `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, `NSString` and `NSNumber` objects (with at least a `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` at top level), once you use `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`, you'll get basic objects named before. Use the classic methods to retrieve it (`objectForKey`:, `for` loops, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@&user_type=%@",_emailID.text,_password.text,@"normal"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration
[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
NSError *jsonError;
NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
NSData *objectData = [requestReply dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                error:&jsonError];// if response contain {} then take NSDictionary and If response contain [] then take NSArray.
NSLog(@"Response: %@", json);
NSString *username = [json valueForKey:@"user_id"];
NSLog(@"username: %@", username);
NSString *emailId = [json valueForKey:@"email"];
NSLog(@"emailId: %@", emailId);
NSString *name = [json valueForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"name: %@", name);
NSString *number = [json valueForKey:@"number"];
NSLog(@"number: %@", number);
}] resume];
```

Comment: Why do you deserialize the JSON using **mutable containers** into an **immutable** object? in almost all cases `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` is not needed at all.

Comment: @omer, what's your requestReply string response? can please update your question with that.

Comment: edited my question check the response. @MahipalSingh

Comment: i have update code, you can view the json string in readable at http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and for more about json parsing please visit these links http://www.appcoda.com/parse-xml-and-json-web-service/ And https://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Comment: it is showing error on "data" that it is not any identifier. In the second line of code. @MahipalSingh

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFConstantString 0x1076408d0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key user_id.'
 when i write requestReply in replace of data it shows error and app crashes. @MahipalSingh

Comment: please check your reponse json dictionary should contain user_id key.

Comment: its is parsing it but showing null in front of every parameter. @MahipalSingh

Comment: i have code according this json, please verify json.   {"user_id":"400","email":"omer.osman@gmail.com","name":"Omer","number":"1234567","password":"pass","user_type":null}

Comment: do u know how to make a check if user enter wrong email or password from a parse data? @MahipalSingh

Comment: you need to add success parameter in api response and check that, if it is true do further activity otherwise just show alert about error.

Comment: Please ask a different question about email/password verification.